# converting 2d string array into 2d double with different length

Tags: java

i am trying to convert a 2d string array into 2d double array. the length of the array is different for each line, so i am unable to convert the array into double. I am getting a null pointer exception error. the file look like this

5 67

1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.456

0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.725

0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -0.150

```
public class first {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   java.io.File test2 = new java.io.File("object.key");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(test2);
   String arr[][]=new String[30][30];
   int i=0,j=0;
   while(input.hasNext())
   {
       String val=input.nextLine();
       j=0;
       if(val.contains(" "))
       {
           String str[]=val.split(" ");
           int cn=str.length;
           while(cn>0)
           {
               arr[i][j]=str[j];
               cn--;
               j++;
               //System.out.println(cn);
           }
       }
       else
           arr[i][j]=val;
       i++;
            }

  double[][] intarray=new double[arr.length][arr.length];
   int kk=0,jj=0;
   for( kk = 0; kk < 16; kk++)
   {
       for(jj=0;jj <arr.length; jj++)
       {
       intarray[kk][jj] = Double.parseDouble(arr[kk][jj]);
       System.out.println(intarray[kk][jj]);
       }
   }
}
}
```

thank you

Comment: What line causes the NullPointerException?

Comment: it reads the first two numbers 5 and 67 and then it points NullPointerException. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to *parseDouble* the *null* value.
This happens because while you declared an array of `[30][30]`, the elements that have not been initialized in the upper loop will be *null*.

If you are not sure which element is likely to be initialized, in the second loop you could simply check and avoid *null* values:

```
for(jj=0;jj <arr.length; jj++)
{
       if (arr[kk][jj] != null) intarray[kk][jj] = Double.parseDouble(arr[kk][jj]);
       System.out.println(intarray[kk][jj]);
}
```

while this is not optimized, at least only initialized values will be processed (then you'll have to check the upper loop and the file to ensure you get numeric values for all non-null elements).

Comment: I understand i am parsingdouble on null, then how can i overcome the issue

Comment: Use the code he posted. Use an if statement to check if the value is null before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at ArrayLists, since you don't know the length of the arrays

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `parseDouble` on `null` value.